# How to saveInstanceState of two fragments committed in different transactions in MainActivity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, transactions, fragmenttransaction

There is one Activity, called `MainActivity`, with layout file below (only two `FrameLayout` as containers).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/tabletux_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabletux_container1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabletux_container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"></FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And two fragments: A and B. 
If I commit a transaction (say, transactionA) to "start" fragment A,

```
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.tabletux_container1, displayFragment, 
                    GeneralConstants.DISPLAY_FRAGMENT_FRAGMENTTRANSACTION_TAG).commit();
```

And then in fragment A (after transactionA), I commited another transaction (say, transactionB) to "start" fragment B.

```
        // This is committed in DisplayFragment, not in MainActivity
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.tabletux_container2, detailFragment, 
                        GeneralConstants.DETAIL_FRAGMENT_FRAGMENTTRANSACTION_TAG).commit();
```

How am I supposed to retrieve fragment B when trying to save the InstanceState of fragment B in `MainActivity`, especially after twice or more times of rotations of the tablet?  
Further Questions:
1. What's the relationship between transactionA and transactionB?
2. Let me make a wild deduction: transactionA and transactionB are in a "transactions pool", so that all fragments committed by any of them can be retrieved from the "pool" by id or tag. If I am wrong, please help correct. 
3. If transactions are separate and have no relations with each other, how am I able to find the fragment in the specific transaction? How can I locate the transaction? 
What I have tried on method `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)`  in `MainActivity`:

```
detailFragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager()
        .findFragmentByTag(GeneralConstants.DETAIL_FRAGMENT_FRAGMENTTRANSACTION_TAG);
```

But this returns `null`. But the fragment "started" in the transaction committed in the `MainActivity` can be located via its tag.

Comment: first of all: do toy really need those two `Fragment`s?

Comment: I could not figure out another solution. How can integrate all into one fragment?

Comment: the question is: why to use Fragments at all?

Comment: For devices like tablets UI support. Large screens, more space. You have better options?

Comment: no, this is the only good reason, i thought you are overusing the Fragments

Answer (score 1):

For your questions, Please refer below link :

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html

According to this guide :

Each fragment transaction is a set of changes that you want to perform at the same time. You can set up all the changes you want to perform for a given transaction using methods such as add(), remove(), and replace(). 
Then, to apply the transaction to the activity, you must call commit().

So you need to change your code as below :

```
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().
            replace(R.id.tabletux_container1, displayFragment,
                    GeneralConstants.DISPLAY_FRAGMENT_FRAGMENTTRANSACTION_TAG)
            .replace(R.id.tabletux_container2, detailFragment,
                    GeneralConstants.DETAIL_FRAGMENT_FRAGMENTTRANSACTION_TAG).commit();
```

Thank you..!!

Comment: It is a good solution. Thank you. But without arguments from fragmentA, I do not know what to be displayed in fragmentB. Maybe I can choose one item set as default argument from fragment A. But if I want to "start" fragment B only after I select something in fragment A, what should I do? Even if I commit both fragments (say, transactionC) in MainActivity, I still need to commit transactions in fragment A (transactionD), can I still find fragment B after transactionD in MainActivity?

Comment: @ Leon : I am sorry i did not get you..If whatever is you talking about has different purpose then please ask new question.And accept this answer.Because in comments i do not think you will get more attention of others also.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tricky solution: in `AndroidManifest.xml` file, add the code below to the activity where the 2 fragments were committed

```
android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"
```

The info provided by the 2 fragments will remain the same, but layout will be tuned according to screen size (For example: GridView will display more columns in horizontal view than in vertical view), which is exactly what I expect.
I could not explain how it works, nor do I know the limitation of such solution.